# View not appearing above annotation

Tags: swift

hi i using mapkit and i have added the annotations to the map however when i click on the annotation is not showing a view above my annotation and in the view it should i have a info button but i don't know why it is not showing this when i run the app on the simulator.

viewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    let mkAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setUpUI()
        mapview.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        determineCurrentLocation()
    }
    
    
    let mapview: MKMapView = {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        //        mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return mapView
    }()
    
    
    func setUpUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setUpConstraint()
    }
    
    func setUpConstraint() {
        view.addSubview(mapview)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mapview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            mapview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            mapview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            mapview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
        
        
    }
    
    func determineCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let mUserLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        mkAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mUserLocation.coordinate.latitude, mUserLocation.coordinate.longitude)


        let users = [
            User(name: "user1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.501203, longitude: -5.13249)),
            User(name: "user2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.500431, longitude: -5.13249)),
            User(name: "user3", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mUserLocation.coordinate.latitude, mUserLocation.coordinate.longitude))
             
        ]
        
        for user in users {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = user.name
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: user.coordinate.latitude, longitude: user.coordinate.longitude)
            mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)
 
        }
        
        
    }
    

    
}
```

MapViewDelegate

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is User else { return nil }
        
        let id = "User"
        var annotationView = mapview.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: id)
 
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: id)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            
            let bioButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = bioButton
        }
        else{
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

image
[annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFOdS.png)

Comment: Unrelated, but any reason why you're not calling super in viewDidAppear? That can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The line in your `else` case in your `MKMapViewDelegate` implementation should also apply in the `if` case. Every annotation view needs an annotation, even the first time they're returned.